# SwiftUI animations of multiple shapes not working correctly

Tags: animation, swiftui, path, shapes

I'm trying to show different shapes as path animation after each other. The animation should start always from showing nothing to the finished shape.
My problem is that it's working just with the first shape, I think because of the `onAppear`. However, after clicking the next button, the next shapes are not animating.
I tried playing with the `pathProgress` value, and another boolean, but either it doesn't animate at all, or it animates backwards.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var id = 1
    @State var pathProgress = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ConsonantDrawing(id: id)
                .trim(from: 0, to: pathProgress)
                .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .animation(.linear(duration: 4.0), value: pathProgress)
                .onAppear {
                    pathProgress = 1.0
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Button {
                    id -= 1
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    id += 1
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.forward.circle")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}

struct ConsonantDrawing: Shape {
    var id: Int
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let width = rect.size.width
        let height = rect.size.height
        
        switch id {
        case 1:
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.12069*width, y: 0.97451*height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.12069*width, y: 0.52102*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.36207*width, y: 0.33497*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.12069*width, y: 0.38149*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.36207*width, y: 0.33497*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.03448*width, y: 0.27684*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.2069*width, y: 0.28846*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.03448*width, y: 0.27684*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.98276*width, y: 0.27684*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.03448*width, y: -0.02549*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.94828*width, y: -0.09526*height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.98276*width, y: 0.97451*height))
            
        case 2:
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.04412*width, y: 0.24668*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.27941*width, y: 0.19048*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.08154*width, y: 0.17525*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.20588*width, y: 0.15476*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.35294*width, y: 0.34524*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.35294*width, y: 0.22619*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.38079*width, y: 0.28888*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.20588*width, y: 0.42857*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.32353*width, y: 0.40476*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.26471*width, y: 0.42857*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.04412*width, y: 0.32143*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.14706*width, y: 0.42857*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.05882*width, y: 0.40476*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.07353*width, y: 0.15476*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.02941*width, y: 0.2381*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.05588*width, y: 0.19048*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.35294*width, y: 0.04762*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.10294*width, y: 0.09524*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.23438*width, y: 0.04762*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.63235*width, y: 0.19048*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.47059*width, y: 0.04762*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.60294*width, y: 0.08333*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.57353*width, y: 0.39286*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.65523*width, y: 0.27381*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.61001*width, y: 0.34856*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.47059*width, y: 0.58333*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.51471*width, y: 0.46429*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.47059*width, y: 0.53571*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.47059*width, y: 0.83333*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.47059*width, y: 0.62143*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.47059*width, y: 0.78571*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.98529*width, y: 0.83333*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.47059*width, y: 1.02381*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.95588*width, y: 1.04762*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.98529*width, y: 0.0119*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.98529*width, y: 0.60714*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.98529*width, y: 0.19048*height))
            
        case 3:
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.03186*width, y: 0.38372*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.27056*width, y: 0.27907*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.04505*width, y: 0.25581*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.19913*width, y: 0.25581*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.34199*width, y: 0.44186*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.34199*width, y: 0.30233*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.36904*width, y: 0.38681*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.17056*width, y: 0.51163*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.31341*width, y: 0.5*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.24198*width, y: 0.52326*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.03186*width, y: 0.38372*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.09913*width, y: 0.5*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.04615*width, y: 0.46512*height))
            path.closeSubpath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.03186*width, y: 0.38372*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.07056*width, y: 0.19767*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.01758*width, y: 0.30233*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.05341*width, y: 0.23256*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.24198*width, y: 0.05814*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.09913*width, y: 0.13953*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.17056*width, y: 0.0814*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.37056*width, y: 0.15116*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.29913*width, y: 0.09302*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.24198*width, y: 0.05814*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.49913*width, y: 0.05814*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.49913*width, y: 0.05814*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.41341*width, y: 0.11628*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.65627*width, y: 0.19767*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.61341*width, y: 0.09302*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.64413*width, y: 0.1532*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.54615*width, y: 0.47674*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.67849*width, y: 0.27907*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.58159*width, y: 0.43348*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.48484*width, y: 0.62791*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.5277*width, y: 0.49927*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.48484*width, y: 0.5814*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.48484*width, y: 0.81395*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.48484*width, y: 0.66512*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.48484*width, y: 0.76744*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.98484*width, y: 0.81395*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.48484*width, y: 1.02326*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.95627*width, y: 1.02326*height))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.98484*width, y: 0.02326*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.98484*width, y: 0.59302*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.98484*width, y: 0.19767*height))
            
        default:
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.12069*width, y: 0.97451*height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.12069*width, y: 0.52102*height))
        }
        
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not resetting `pathProgress`. What I did was to reset it when pressing the back or next buttons and checking wheter the current `id` was the first or the last one to avoid issue with animations.
I also removed the `.animation` modifier on the `ConsonantDrawing` view because it was causing issues and placed the animtion in the actions rather:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var id = 1
    @State var pathProgress = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ConsonantDrawing(id: id)
                .trim(from: 0, to: pathProgress)
                .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                /// Remove this .animation line because is part of the issue!
                //.animation(.linear(duration: 4.0), value: pathProgress)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Button {
                    guard id != 1 else { return }
                    id -= 1
                    pathProgress = 0
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4)) {
                        pathProgress = 1.0
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    guard id != 3 else { return }
                    pathProgress = 0
                    id += 1
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4)) {
                            pathProgress = 1.0
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.forward.circle")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("On appear")
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4)) {
                pathProgress = 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Consonant Drawing]

Let me know how'd you find this soltution!

Comment: Thanks for the clear help. In your result animation, as well as on my device, when I click next, before the animation has finished, there is a small pause and then the next animation runs faster in the beginning. Is there a way to influence this?

Comment: I can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

`.animation(.linear(duration: 4.0), value: pathProgress)` animates `pathProgress` every time it changes. You don't seem to want that. From what I understand, you don't want an animation when `pathProgress` is set to 0 - it should only animate when `pathProgress` is set to 1.

So you should remove `.animation(.linear(duration: 4.0), value: pathProgress)`. Use `withAnimation` whenever you want to animate, and don't use it when you don't want to animate.

```
VStack {
    ConsonantDrawing(id: id)
        .trim(from: 0, to: pathProgress)
        .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4.0)) {
                pathProgress = 1.0
            }
        }
    
    Spacer()
    
    HStack {
        Button {
            id -= 1
            pathProgress = 0
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4.0)) {
                pathProgress = 1.0
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle")
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        Button {
            id += 1
            pathProgress = 0
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4.0)) {
                pathProgress = 1.0
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.forward.circle")
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .font(.largeTitle)
}
```